# practical example of defining using metaclass like setting it to ABCMeta or LoggingType

Tags: python, logging, metaclass, abc

Example of setting metaclass to `LoggingType` i spotted at my workplace.

```
import logging as _logging
class SomeClass(object):
    __metaclass__ = _logging.LoggingType
```

Here is the example I have seen for `ABCMeta` set to `__metaclass__`

I want to know the practical advantage if their is any example of setting ABCMeta as metaclass as shown below: from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html)

```
from abc import ABCMeta

class MyABC:
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta
```

to me my question sounds like how to take advantage of

```
 register(subclass)

    Register subclass as a “virtual subclass”
```

How can we benefit from it ?

If you find my question is repeated please link this post up !!

Answer (score 0):

> Abstract base classes are a form of interface checking more strict
>   than individual `hasattr()` checks for particular methods. By defining
>   an abstract base class, you can define a common API for a set of
>   subclasses. This capability is especially useful in situations where a
>   third-party is going to provide implementations, such as with plugins
>   to an application, but can also aid you when working on a large team
>   or with a large code-base where keeping all classes in your head at
>   the same time is difficult or not possible.

Reference: http://pymotw.com/2/abc/